# How to detect detect hardware buttons (physical device) in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to lock the power / lock button, I need to be able to control that button press to prevent my app from crashing.

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons, I ran tests on 2 cell phone brands and it only works on Samsung, the other brand is Huawei and it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if you have any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What buttons do you need? Why do you need them?

Comment: Hi Andrej, my english is not good I hope you understand me, my application works with map and geofence, I have an event that gets the time when entering a geofence, the problem is that the application stops working when you press the lock button, I need prevent blocking, so that my application continues to work.